# How can I make my Google Compute Engine instance follow App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Google CloudSQL gives the option to allow it to follow an App Engine app for better performance.

How can I do the same with a Google Compute Engine instance? Otherwise what is the best Google data center to house my instance for best performance with a US based App Engine app?

Comment: @konqi please can you add back the rest of my question as I don't think you understood it. It isn't off-topic. The question's title asks how can Google Compute Engine follow App Engine. I would like an answer that either allows it to be done automatically (ideal) or manually. You just removed the bit asking how it can be done manually by purposefully situating my Google Compute Engine instance in a data center close to my App Engine instance.

Comment: @konqi thanks that's nice and clear.

Comment: I don't think it is. Maybe add the content of your comment to the question or say 'Google data center' instead of just 'data center'? Also: You can't make a compute instance follow an app engine instance. You could trigger the start of an instance in your app engine warmup (via compute api) but that's a really bad idea.

Comment: Depending on what you're actually trying to do the way to go might be an app with two modules, one of which is a managed vm.

Comment: Managed VM would be great but I need persistent disk space and a binary to execute in the background.

Comment: mh in my understanding of managed vms this should be possible. For persistent disk space you could mount cloud storage with fuse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96046/discussion-between-dan-and-konqi).

Comment: @konqi is it possible to post your comment as an answer so that anyone searching for such a question can benefit from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve the way to go might be an app with two modules, one of which is a [managed vm](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/).

If you need a persistent disk in your managed vm you can [mount cloud storage with fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) in your managed vm.

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion is not a good match for my case as Fuse does not do well with low latency small reads and Managed VMs can restart every 24h and my app has a large startup overhead.

Comment: @Dan that's okay, maybe this solution works for others, so i'll just leave it here. I would try to reduce that overhead since it will become a problem independent from how you start VMs. One of the projects i worked on used a snapshot to create new VMs from, maybe that can work for you as well.

Comment: I completely agree with reducing startup overhead etc. I inherited the app and will massage it into shape over time. Thanks for your help.